# iphone-uiview-background

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development.  I have one XIB file, the login page (a form).

Now I want to set the `UIView` background image.

When I supply an image from Interface Builder then there is no effect, and when I set it from the code then also no effect.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"srk_ipad_Homepg.png"]];
```

I don't want to use a `UIImageView` because when I place an image, all my controls are hidden behind the `UIView`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use UIImageView to set a background without harm, you just have to move it to the top of the view hierarchy. Look at this splashscreen view:

[image]

And this is the view's hierarchy tree:

[image]

This will prevent your controls from being covered.